# Pushbutton zoom in and zoom out in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I need code to pushbuttons "zoom in", "zoom out" for my image. Trying to used this but wrong. Please, help me. I work with the  MATLAB Gui.

[image]

```
function btnZoomIn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','ZoomIn','Units','pixels',...
'Position',[90 10 60 20],'Enable','off',...
'Tag','btnZoomIn','Callback',@btnZoomIn_Callback);
h = guihandles(hObject);
set(h.btnZoomOut,'Enable','on')
data = guidata(hObject);
data.magnif = data.magnif+1;
guidata(hObject, data)

function btnZoomOut_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Zoom Out','Units','pixels',...
'Position',[160 10 60 20],'Enable','off',...
'Tag','btnZoomOut','Callback',@btnZoomOut_Callback);

h = guihandles(hObject);
data = guidata(hObject);
if data.magnif > 1
 data.magnif = data.magnif-1;
  if data.magnif == 1
```

Comment: Use [`zoom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html) in your button callbacks, there's no reason to try and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Also this code doesn't really make sense, you are creating the pushbuttons inside their callbacks?

Comment: At the University the teacher gave us the assignment to do of the zoom button. And nobody knows how to do it.
I told that I don't know the programm. It's just silly try :(

Comment: I would suggest talking to your professor.

Comment: The problem is that the professor himself does not know how to do the program. He just wants the result.

Comment: I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Is russian education. We need to accept it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be cheeky about it (hopefully that idiom translates...), you could just point your professor to the built-in zoom buttons.

A (non-GUIDE) example:

```
f = figure;
ax = axes('Parent', f, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.18 0.8 0.8]);
A = imread('ngc6543a.jpg'); % Read a built-in image as a sample
image(A, 'Parent', ax);
```

[image: yay]

However, if you need a serious answer, see MATLAB's [`zoom`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html) function, which you can add to your button callbacks.

To expand on the above example:

```
f = figure;
ax = axes('Parent', f, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.1 0.18 0.8 0.8]);
A = imread('ngc6543a.jpg'); % Read a built-in image as a sample
image(A, 'Parent', ax);

zoomonbutton = uicontrol('Parent', f, ...
                         'Style', 'pushbutton', ...
                         'Units', 'Normalized', ...
                         'Position', [0.1 0.02 0.4 0.1], ...
                         'String', 'Zoom On', ...
                         'Callback', 'zoom on' ...
                         );

zoomoffbutton = uicontrol('Parent', f, ...
                         'Style', 'pushbutton', ...
                         'Units', 'Normalized', ...
                         'Position', [0.5 0.02 0.4 0.1], ...
                         'String', 'Zoom Off', ...
                         'Callback', 'zoom off' ...
                         );
```

[image: yay2]

Where pushing the 'on' button turns on Interactive Zooming. From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html):

> `zoom on` turns on interactive zooming. When interactive zooming is
>   enabled in a figure, pressing a mouse button while your cursor is
>   within an axes zooms into the point or out from the point beneath the
>   mouse. Zooming changes the axes limits. When using zoom mode, you
>
> ```
> Zoom in by positioning the mouse cursor where you want the center of the plot to be and either
>
>     Press the mouse button or
>
>     Rotate the mouse scroll wheel away from you (upward).
>
> Zoom out by positioning the mouse cursor where you want the center of the plot to be and either
>
>     Simultaneously press Shift and the mouse button, or
>
>     Rotate the mouse scroll wheel toward you (downward).
> ```

And pushing the 'off' button turns off this interactive mode.

---

Hopefully this helps you in the right direction. I would recommend you investigate MATLAB's documentation, it's very comprehensive and has many examples.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I hope that something can be done with that.